# What is the most efficient way to pull multiple rows from mysql by their ids?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a typical situation, where I need pull multiple rows from mysql by their ID's. I only know two methods how to do so, but **I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this?** and if there isn't, **then which one of my own methods is most neatest/fastest/better?**

**My 1st method:** *(~0.0003030)*

```
$ids = array(3, 4, 6, 11);

foreach ($ids as $id) {
    $task = $DB->query_first("SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE `id` = '$id'");
    DoSomethingWithTheTask($task);
}
```

**My 2nd method:** *(~0.0001040)*

```
$ids = array(3, 4, 6, 11);

foreach ($ids as $id) {
    $wheres[] = '`id` = \'' . $id . '\'';
}

$tasks = $DB->query("SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE " . implode(' OR ', $wheres));

while ($task = $DB->fetch_array($tasks)) {
    DoSomethingWithTheTask($task);
}
```

The reason why I'm even considering the second method, is because it uses only 1x query.. However, I strongly believe that both of these methods are not neat and need to be optimized. As far as I know, you cannot make a query like this: `WHERE id = '2, 3, 4'`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, you can. IN operator does that.

```
SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE `id` IN (2, 3, 4)
```

would do the trick. you can use both numeric or string values with IN operator

As Johan failed with example, here is a right way

```
$ids = array(3, 4, 6, 11);
$in  = implode(",",$ids);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE `id` IN ($in)");
```

for the frequent use I'd make a placeholder, to call the whole expression this way

```
$ids  = array(3, 4, 6, 11);
$data = $db->getArr("SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE `id` IN (?a)",$ids);
```

to answer your questions from the comments, here is a code from my db class

```
function escapeString($value)
{
    return  "'".mysql_real_escape_string($value,$this->connect)."'";
}
function createIN($data)
{
    if (!is_array($data))
    {
        throw new E_DB_MySQL_parser("Value for ?a type placeholder should be array.");
    }
    if (!$data)
    {
        throw new E_DB_MySQL_parser("Empty array for ?a type placeholder.");
    }
    $query = $comma = '';
    foreach ($data as $key => $value)
    {
        $query .= $comma.$this->escapeString($value);
        $comma  = ",";
    }
    return $query;
}
```

getArr() method has no direct relation to this as it's responsible for only type of result.

Comment: Politeness isn't strong with this one.

Comment: What happens, if `$ids` is not an array or is empty?

Comment: @Kalle H. that's good question. a syntax error. So, you have to check for both cases. So I do in my placeholder handler.

Comment: @NB, Col Shrapnel does not need to be polite. because 99% of the time he is correct. Every run-in I have with him I learn something.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: Wonderful! I had some issues at first, but figured them out. I first tried `id IN ('$id')` -> `id IN ('3, 4, 6, 11')` and got only the first result (3#). But, correct would be `id IN ('3', '4', '6', '11')`. This method works perfectly. I cannot thank you enough.  I added microtime() results to my question. Your methods result is **~0.0000930**, this makes a lot of difference in my projects, old and upcoming. Thanks!! And thanks to Johan as well :)

Comment: @Kalle in case of numbers you don't need to quote them. However, for the compatimility, you can treat numbers as trings. in this case you will need another way of escaping.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: What if, the array contains names with spaces? `$names = array('Kalle H. Väravas', 'Col. Shrapnel');` and then `name IN (" . implode(', ', $names) . ")`. This comes to subject when creating `$db->getArr();`, don't want to limit its features on numeric-arrays only :/

Comment: @Kalle no problem, you can use this operator for the strings as well. However, you need to use another "glue" for implode, as just a comma is not suffucient, as well as another way to escape strings

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: Thanks, I added a function to my db class similar to your createIN(). This question is turning out to be highly educational ^^